# How can I connect to a API using fetch and bearer token?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, bearer-token

I would like to connect to REST API that uses a token Bearer.
I try the JS code below:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('MCToken',
    JSON.stringify('123456')
);

let datastructuresAPI = () => {
    let token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('MCToken'));
    let header = new Headers({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let response = fetch('https://mon_url',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: header,
        body:JSON.stringify({
            "methodName":"connect",
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            "serviceName":"ConnectionService"
        }),
        'x-frame': 'same-origin',
        mode: 'no-cors'       
    });
    console.log(response)
}
datastructuresAPI();
```

But I can’t connect, I have these message (the first is the result of the `console.log`)

[image]

[image]

Comment: 401 is the HTTP Status code for Unauthorized. I'm guessing the you did connect, but the token is invalid (`123456` is not typically a valid token).

Comment: Yes, '123456' is not the real token. I have tested with the good token bearer

Answer (score 0):

With [a few exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_request_header), setting headers on a cross-origin Ajax request requires permission via [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Since you set `mode: 'no-cors'`, you told the browser to *silently* fail when trying anything that requires permission via CORS.

Consequently, the `Authorization` header is not set and the `Content-Type` defaults to `text/plain`.

The server then issues a 401 response because, presumably, the `Authorization` header was missing.

- **Don't** set `mode: 'no-cors'`
- **Do** configure the server to grant permission with CORS **or** make the request to the server from your own server side code instead of directly from a browser.

Answer (score -2):

Fetch function is an async function and you should wait it.

```
fetch(...)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

For the other result (401) are you sure that your REST API waits token with Bearer {token}? It could be only {token}.

Comment: I added in the the code « then » and « catch », and I obtained the same result. Yes, I am sure the API used bearer token